# Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' - Debian 8 , PHP 7.2

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7.2

I have a VPS with Debian 8 OS and a DirectAdmin panel with PHP7.2

To use MongoDB PHP driver, I installed it with the command `sudo pecl install mongodb`.

After that installation, I added the driver extension to the php.ini file by this command:

```
echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"
```

But it seems that driver not installed! Because when I exec a PHP command, face this warning:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so'
>   (tried:
>   /usr/local/php72/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongodb.so
>   (/usr/local/php72/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongodb.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory),
>   /usr/local/php72/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongodb.so.so
>   (/usr/local/php72/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongodb.so.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown
>   on line 0

Everything is ok in my local (windows), I add the *Non Thread Safe (NTS)* driver extension to the extensions directory, and It's all!

What I did wrong?
Is installation of MongoDB driver on the PHP of DirectAdmin different from installation on a normal PHP?

**Update:**

MongoDB is not in the result of `phpinfo();` too!

Comment: Does the file `mongodb.so` exist in the extension dir? Because the error says it does not.

Comment: If you mean `/usr/local/php72/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/`, No! there are just two files, `opcache.a` and `opcache.so`

Comment: Yea so fix your `extension_dir` configuration and put the `.so` files in the appropriate folder, problem solved.

Comment: I really don't know how should I do! where is the extension `.so` file, what do you mean fix!

Comment: The `mongodb.so` file is installed in the extensions dir which is the one before you changed it..... what folders are in `/usr/local/php72/lib/php/extensions` ? Or simply use `find` and search for the file

Comment: If the file does not exist and you change the extensions dir folder, how do you even expect it to work, of course mongodb is not loaded.

Comment: but I did not change it before! only `no-debug-non-zts-20170718` is in the mentioned directory!

Comment: When you install via pecl `sudo pecl install mongodb` it tells you where it did install to

Comment: I just pressed Enter and let it default. and I did not see what you said

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure php extension dir is:
`/usr/local/php72/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/`

Check:

```
php -i |grep extension_dir
```

If not, there are two options to do it:

1. modify `extension_dir` in `php.ini` to
   `/usr/local/php72/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/`
2. `echo "extension=/full_path_through_pecl_installed/mongodb.so" >
   php.ini`

Comment: the location is exactly what you mentioned. but how can I check that MongoDB extension is in there or any other valid directory that should be? It's just two files in that directory

Comment: follow your update, please make sure that result of `php -i |grep extension_dir` and `phpinfo()` are the same. by the way make sure php cli `php.ini` and fpm `php.ini` are the same file.

Comment: after that warning, here is my result: `extension_dir => /usr/local/php72/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718 => /usr/local/php72/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value`

Comment: fpm and php(cli) may use different `php.ini`

Comment: How should I check it? and also the values of phpinfo and that command are equal

Answer (score 0):

The issue was about DirectAdmin because it has its own PHP and extensions must add on it.

When I run `sudo pecl install mongodb`, It looks out default VPS PHP.

This command solved my problem:

```
cp /usr/lib/php/20170718/mongodb.so /usr/local/php72/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongodb.so
```